# AlarmManager is not working after app is closed? - Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have a small problem about alarmmanager but I couldn't find a answer which fits to my code.

My question is simple. I have a list of alarms which is set to future. While my app is running, I can recieve Notification.

But when I close my app, It doesn't send notification to me and if I run my app again, past notifications can be seen in notification center.

Here is my codes.
In MainActivity.java I use this method which can take a Person List and sets alarm of each of Person. I run this method in onCreate()

```
private void createScheduledNotification(List<Person> people)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<people.size();i++) {

        // Get new calendar object
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, people.get(i).getMonth());
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, people.get(i).getDay());
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, people.get(i).getHour());
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, people.get(i).getMinute());
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        // Retrieve alarm manager from the system
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getBaseContext().ALARM_SERVICE);
        // Every scheduled intent needs a different ID, else it is just executed once
        int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

        // Prepare the intent which should be launched at the date
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimeAlarm.class);
        intent.putExtra("person", people.get(i));
        // Prepare the pending intent
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // Register the alert in the system. You have the option to define if the device has to wake up on the alert or not
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

And I have a TimeAlarm class which extends BroadcastReciever.

```
public class TimeAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

private Person person;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent paramIntent) {

    Bundle bundle = paramIntent.getExtras();
    person = (Person) bundle.getSerializable("person");
    // Request the notification manager
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Create a new intent which will be fired if you click on the notification
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");

    // Attach the intent to a pending intent
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // Create the notification
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.logo24px, "Never Forget", System.currentTimeMillis());
    //
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "It's " + person.getName() + " " + person.getSname() + "'s Birthday!", "Celebrate his/her birthday! ",pendingIntent);

    // Fire the notification
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
}
}
```

Also I add these lines to AndroidManifest.xml

```
        <receiver android:name=".TimeAlarm" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

It works fine when app is running but when I close my app in Active Applications page, it doesn't send any notification.

Answer (score 3):

Try use this when you create your intent

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putSerializable("person", people.get(i));
intent.putExtras(extras);
```

And in your BroadcastReciver check if the action is a boot completed action. (it could also be your alarm).

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent paramIntent) {
                     //CHECK IF IS BOOT COPLETED 
                 if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
                            /* Setting the alarm here Alarm are automatically cleaned on phone shutdown*/}
                 else{
                        Bundle bundle = paramIntent.getExtras();
                        person = (Person) bundle.getSerializable("person");
                        // Request the notification manager
                        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                        // Create a new intent which will be fired if you click on the notification
                        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");

                        // Attach the intent to a pending intent
                        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                        // Create the notification
                        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.logo24px, "Never Forget", System.currentTimeMillis());
                        //
                        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "It's " + person.getName() + " " + person.getSname() + "'s Birthday!", "Celebrate his/her birthday! ",pendingIntent);

                        // Fire the notification
                        notificationManager.notify(1, notification);}
                    }
    }
```

Also check this

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

because it seems that you are continusly updating the same intent, is what you want?

**Edit:**

Sorry I didn't remember to insert it, your reciever declaration sholuld be like this.

```
<receiver android:name=".TimeAlarm" 
        android:process=":remote"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```